# Update ImageField using Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using REST framework for creating APIs.

I have ImageField to store Images.

```py
class GeneralInfo(models.Model):
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logo/")
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now using PUT request, I want to update the logo which is ImageField.

Serializer class looks like this:

```py
class GeneralInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GeneralInfo
        fields = ["id", "school_name", "address"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return GeneralInfo.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.logo = validated_data.get("logo", instance.logo)
        instance.school_name = validated_data.get("school_name", instance.school_name)
        instance.address = validated_data.get("address", instance.address)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There's no `logo` in the `fields` attribute;

It should be `fields = ["id", "logo", "school_name", "address"]`